# How to get the python command to go back to using python 2.7 Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, alias

So I made a mistake and routed the python command to point to python 3.6.9 and now certain programs (namely ROS packages) are having issues.  I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.  I see lots of tutorials telling people how to alias python to python3 but not how to fix this issue.  Also I tried to unalias python, but that did nothing.

So now when I run python --version OR python3 --version I see python 3.6.9

And when I run pip --version OR pip3 --version I see pip 20.1.1 from /home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

Comment: You have to stop using python 2.7

Comment: @mama thats not really helpfull for ubuntu if you install packages for ubuntu that rely on python-2.7  ... thats quite different from leisurely coding  python  yourself...

Comment: @ildaniel - you might want to search superuser for adviceon that matter - we care about coding and setting up ubuntu, while we might need to do that to code, is more of a "need to do thing".

Comment: I'm just saying it because python 2.7 is not maintained anymore. So the Ubuntu packages that are using python 2.7 should be considered out of date...

Comment: @Patrick Artner Thank you I'll check that out.  I don't use python 2.7 by choice, but certain packages that I need and are no longer maintained require it.

Comment: You can add `alias python=/usr/bin/python` to the end of your ~/.bashrc file , but to only temporarily solve this problem until you find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install an isolated Python 2.7 in your system and actually have several versions of Python. One of the easiest ways is [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

You can do it like this:

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yyuu/pyenv-installer/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash
```

Follow the instructions, you may need to reload your env (re-log in into the console).

Then install and set Python 2.7 as a default Python:

```
pyenv global 2.7.18
```